# What do I lose if I use OpenID instead of the custom login system I built

Tags: web-applications, authentication, openid

I'm trying to make the decision whether to use OpenID or stay with a well-built custom login system. I think the appeal of OpenID is clear, in that the user doesn't have to create yet another account to log into your site. But can you help me answer the question: What do I lose if I use OpenID instead of the custom login system I built?

P.S. Check out [my related question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81977), OpenID and data espionage, on Programmers StackExchange.

Comment: Nothing says you can't allow both types of logins.

Comment: You lose the ability to give hackers access to all your users' passwords.

Comment: If you haven't yet, check out StackOverflow's comments on the tradeoffs they've encountered: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/

Comment: @jalf, I said "well-built" :) i.e. hashed, salted, put a lot of effort into designing it.

Comment: @ceejayoz, That's the plan, but I'm afraid if both are present, the users may gravitate more towards the easier route and it will end up being the default imposed on us anyway.

Comment: So? Are you sure there isn't a bug in the system somewhere? Or that there isn't a XSS exploit on your website, or something else that might allow an attacker to discover the user's password? My point is that with OpenID, you never even *see* the users password, so even if you screw up, the damage is limited.

Comment: @jalf, OK, but if you focus on the security aspect, the same thing could be said about OpenID. OpenID is much more susceptible to Phishing (someone could get the OpenID login information by directing the user to a form that just looks like the original form). If the user's account has been phished, I as another third party site am at risk. The password was stolen from the user, and the attacker could use the phished login to get the user's data on my site as well as any other site the user is on. Comment?

Comment: @Hostile Fork, Thanks for the link, reading it now. Nice that the guys at SO are sharing and wrote up something.

Comment: @sameold: the difference is that OpenID allows the user to pick a provider that they trust. And while phising is always a concern, I tend to have more trust in an OpenID provider to write a secure solution, than in Joe Average Webcoder. No offense.

Comment: Anyway, OpenID has its flaws, certainly, but my point is that I feel web developers tend to underestimate two important factors: how hard it is to write secure code, and how many *other* login systems the user already has to keep track of, and how disinclined he'll be to registering a new account with a new password *just for you*.

Comment: jalf has covered most of the points but I would also add one more thing: in case the OpenID provider does get hacked, you will (generally) not be liable for the damage (unless you somehow contributed). Security issues are between the security provider and the user, and with the recent Sony news, I don't know why anybody would want to have that kind of liability on their hands anyway.

Comment: @Lirik, As far as I remember, the issue with Sony wasn't just the login, but the way the financial data was stored on their system. I doubt handing your login routing to Yahoo or Google would have saved them there because the financial data on the account was stored incorrectly. Login implementation and financial data storage are 2 different things, so I think your point is moot.

Comment: @sameold, I wasn't suggesting that Sony would not have been hacked if they used OpenID nor did I even imply it... what I'm saying is that even big corporations with huge security budgets have a hard time getting the security right. When they do get attacked, then they are liable for the lost information, regardless if it's financial or otherwise. If you don't hold any personal information then you have no information to loose, so you're not liable for losses. Liability has nothing to do with the type of information you loose, regardless if it's login or financial!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you will not loose much if its a standard login - it may even be better, but consider the fact that your website might grow and you may need to change the way your users log in. I personally like coding my own login systems, they are not difficult and you know exactly what it is doing.

If you go with openID you may get more sign-ins / sign-ups to your site, however if you are debating it - why not just have your system to log in - and the openID system, if your system is already designed then it shouldn't be too much work!

Hope this helps!

Comment: People who "like making their own login system" should be shot on sight. I'm sick to death of having to keep track of 900 different logins and passwords because every code monkey who ever learned to hack two lines of PHP code together decided that "I must have my own login system". No offense to you specifically, but the attitude that "there's no downside to my custom proprietary login system" annoys me. It encourages incompetent coders to mess around with their users' sensitive information, and it is a pain for users who have to create *yet another account* on yet another site.

Comment: I'm not talking about rubbishy sites here, there is no way I would put a username and password into a system that I thought wasn't md5 hashed - but openID does not give out personal details anyway - if the designer wants those he has to ask and store them himself - which means he will have access anyway. As long as you have salted, and used md5 or other such suitable encryption in your database or where-ever you are keeping data you are ok (also make sure you have an ssl certificate)

Comment: @Grant: but you are posting an answer on a popular Q&A site saying, with no qualifications or conditions, that "it is not difficult" to write your own login system, and giving the impression that you encourage doing so. (by the way, MD5 WAS BROKEN YEARS AGO! So much for your "safe" login systems, and for "knowing what I'm doing")

Comment: and of course, you sidestepped my other concern: that the user doesn't *want* to have to create Yet Another Login *just because you like writing login systems*

Comment: @jalf, easy there! I too don't support the idea of coding your own login system and your comments are correct, but you're just a little harsh! Furthermore, you wrote 1069 characters worth of comments... this could have been an answer on its own.

Comment: @Link: except it wouldn't have been very useful as an answer. I'm not really answering the OP's question, after all. :)